# Hibernate DSL keyword searching in Infinispan

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-search, infinispan

I'm using Hibernate DSL in Infinispan for searching.

And there is a problem when I use keyword query.

First, here is the mapping class:

```
mapping
  .analyzerDef("fr",StandardTokenizerFactory.class)
    .filter(LowerCaseFilterFactory.class)
  .entity(DatatypeProperty.class).indexed().providedId()
    .property("rdfResource",ElementType.FIELD).field().analyze(Analyze.NO).store(Store.YES)
    .property("typeId",ElementType.FIELD).field().analyze(Analyze.NO)
    .property("xmlLang",ElementType.FIELD).field().analyze(Analyze.NO)
    .property("normVal", ElementType.FIELD).field().analyzer("fr");
```

And there is the data I add in the cache:

```
dpId====>> DP_1464688  rdfResource====>> HPO_TE_HP:0002099  NormVal====>> asthme xmlLang====>> fr
dpId====>> DP_2009562  rdfResource====>> MDR_PT_10003553  NormVal====>> asthme  xmlLang====>> fr
dpId====>> DP_914319   rdfResource====>> MED_T_T2  NormVal====>> asthme  xmlLang====>> fr
dpId====>> DP_8271402  rdfResource====>> MSH_M_0001885  NormVal====>> asthme  xmlLang====>> fr
dpId====>> DP_4432234  rdfResource====>> MSH_D_001249  NormVal====>> asthme  xmlLang====>> fr
```

The query for searching:

```
Query query1 = queryBuilder
                .bool()
                .must(queryBuilder.keyword().onField("normVal").matching("asthme").createQuery())
                .must(queryBuilder.keyword().onField("xmlLang").matching("fr").createQuery())
                .createQuery();
test = CSECore.searchManager.getQuery(query1, DatatypeProperty.class).list();
```

But no one exist in the result of searching.

***PS:*** There is a property ***"normVal"*** of ***MSH_D_001249*** whose content is ***"asthme bronchique"***;
If I add this in the cache, the ***MSH_D_001249*** will appear in the result.

Someone has idea for this???

Comment: Looks correct to me. Often analyzer configuration and usage is a common problem, but the way you describe it, it should work.